# How to root Moto E

Tags: rooting, 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-e

I have a Moto E and I want to root it so I can have more access. I can't link my SD card to my apps or connect SD or hotspot because it says I don't have root permission.

Comment: Did you try searching on web? It could be that you tried something but didn't work, and it's better to detail your research so that the answerer can avoid it suggesting at last. Also, have you tried **Methods/apps** in this [rooting index](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device)?

Answer (score 2):

Follow steps below:

**This will void your warranty!**

You need a custom recovery installed like **TWRP**

> **How to Root Motorola Moto E**
>
> 1. From [here](http://download.chainfire.eu/396/SuperSU/UPDATE-SuperSU-v1.94.zip) download the SuperSU app file.Place this file on your computer, preferable on desktop – don’t unzip it.
> 2. Then connect your Moto E with your PC by plugging in the USB cord.
> 3. Up next, transfer the root file from desktop to your phone’s SD card.
> 4. Unplug the USB cord and turn off your device.
> 5. Enter recovery mode on your Motorola Moto E.
> 6. Then from recovery select “install zip from SD card” followed by “choose zip from SD card”.
> 7. Pick the root file which you have downloaded before and flash the same on your Moto E.
> 8. Wait while the installation procedure is being completed.
> 9. In the end select “reboot system now” and you are done.

More information: http://www.android.gs/root-motorola-moto-e/

Comment: The user doesn't have the custom recovery installed.

Comment: @AleksanderStefanovic I updated answer, and did you down vote? If so please up vote.

Comment: of course, if you've improved your answer, the previous downvote should be removed. So, there you go.

Comment: Is this process OS dependent? I mean my Moto E (condor) has Lollipop 5.1 as the OS. So will the above process work for me?